# Need error handling example for IPP.NET QBO

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I will be writing code to insert journal entries, invoices, and credit memos into Quickbooks Online.  I may do this in a loop inserting one at a time, or I may use a batch process, which I think uses BatchRequest and BatchResponse.  Can anyone show me an example of the error handling that I could use to verify the insert or report back the reason for a failure to the user?  I am interested in examples for both the individual transaction insert and for getting the errors from a BatchResponse.

Answer (score 2):

The DevKit will throw an exception if an error occurs. The exceptions are listed here:

http://developer.intuit.com/IntuitDataServicesSDK/?topic=html/714c1b2e-3473-fadd-0753-358ebb114480.htm

Comment: Any chance you type out a couple lines of example code to show how I get the exception?

Comment: As I read your response more closely, I am wondering if the syntax would be something like Try (insert transaction) Catch ex as Intuit.Ipp.Exception.FaultException...

Comment: It appears that the normal syntax of Try Catch ex as Exception will return ex.Message with a description of the error for a single request.  I am not sure if that is the preferred syntax.